# Plotly python spline in ternary space

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, interpolation, ternary

I'm trying to draw a spline, or interpolated line, in plotly python, however, it doesn't seem possible with the usual spline option since the curve doubles back on itself. Is there a way to achieve a smooth curve in this instance? Are there other libraries that might do the job that I can call?

Edit: sample data

a = array([0.15, 0.15, 0.17, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.41, 0.47, 0.48, 0.51, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.63, 0.65, 0.69, 0.73, 0.74])

b = array([0.14, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.05, 0.16, 0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25])

c = array([0.71, 0.7 , 0.73, 0.63, 0.62, 0.58, 0.69, 0.57, 0.56, 0.67, 0.65, 0.51, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.4 , 0.39, 0.35, 0.34, 0.31, 0.28, 0.23, 0.18, 0.16, 0.13, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01])

Example code...

```
    fig5 = go.Figure(go.Scatterternary({
    'mode': 'lines',
    'connectgaps': True,
    'a': a6,
    'b': b6,
    'c': c6,
    'line': {'color': 'black', 'shape': 'spline', 'smoothing': 1},
    'marker': {'size': 2, 'line': {'width': 0.1}}
    })
    )    
fig5.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
    'mode': 'markers',
    'a': a6,
    'b': b6,
    'c': c6,
    'marker': {'size': 2},
    'connectgaps': True,
    })
    )
fig5.show(renderer="svg")
```

[image: Points and attempted smooth line...]

Comment: You will need to reorder the points so that the points that "double back" on themselves come last in the a6, b6, c6 arrays. I don't know if there is a algorithmic way to do this, but I will definitely add an answer if I think of anything

Comment: Thanks. That is something I also wanted to try, but I don't know how to sort the arrays.

Comment: thanks for posting your sample data! that will help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the geometry of the triangular coordinates to isolate portions of the curve you want to separate, then use a condition to select this portion of the data. For example, if we select the following portion of the curve:

[image]

This can be isolated with a rule like `(b < 0.15) & (c > 0.6)`. To make this process a bit more general, I wrote a function that allows you to pass lists of indices you want to plot, and the scatter and spline are drawn for these groups separately. You can break the curve up into as many pieces as needed this way.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

a = np.array([0.15, 0.15, 0.17, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.41, 0.47, 0.48, 0.51, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.59, 0.62, 0.63, 0.65, 0.69, 0.73, 0.74])
b = np.array([0.14, 0.15, 0.1 , 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.05, 0.16, 0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.22, 0.24, 0.25, 0.25])
c = np.array([0.71, 0.7 , 0.73, 0.63, 0.62, 0.58, 0.69, 0.57, 0.56, 0.67, 0.65, 0.51, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.45, 0.4 , 0.39, 0.35, 0.34, 0.31, 0.28, 0.23, 0.18, 0.16, 0.13, 0.07, 0.02, 0.01])

fig = go.Figure()

curve_portion = np.where((b < 0.15) & (c > 0.6))
curve_other_portion = np.where(~((b < 0.15) & (c > 0.6)))

def add_plot_spline_portions(fig, indices_groupings):
    for indices in indices_groupings:
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
            'mode': 'lines',
            'connectgaps': True,
            'a': a[indices],
            'b': b[indices],
            'c': c[indices],
            'line': {'color': 'black', 'shape': 'spline', 'smoothing': 1},
            'marker': {'size': 2, 'line': {'width': 0.1}}
            })
            )    

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatterternary({
            'mode': 'markers',
            'a': a[indices],
            'b': b[indices],
            'c': c[indices],
            'marker': {'size': 10, 'color': 'red'},
            'connectgaps': True,
            })
            )

add_plot_spline_portions(fig, [curve_portion, curve_other_portion])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Derek. This indeed solves my question, but I realized after trying it out with the full dataset that what I really need is a trendline that creates a smooth line between points rather than point-to-point lines.

Comment: Can't edit my top comment... The problem is that I don't think that the trendline option is available in plotly for ternary diagrams.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks for clearing that up. it sounds like the question you asked here isn't exactly the question you intended to ask (as interpolation, to my understanding, means perfectly going through each point) whereas it sounds like what you really meant to ask about is regression (such as a polynomial of best fit).

Comment: What I would do is upvote or accept this answer (if you think it answers the question being asked) so that in case other people have the same question about spline interpolation, they'll be directed to this answer. then you can create a new question asking specifically about trendlines for ternary plot diagrams. I would be happy to take a look and see if I can think of a workaround or if there's a way to build a trendline for ternary plot diagrams from scratch

Comment: Sounds good to me. I think this will be helpful to others, indeed.